# K8S audit logs- where can i find status code options

Tags: kubernetes, audit

in K8S audit logs we get the responseStatus with different "code" number.
where can i find all the options that can be return by K8S?

```
        "responseStatus": {
            "metadata": {},
            "status": "Failure",
            "reason": "Invalid",
            "code": 422
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are basically HTTP status. In this case it is [HTTP 422](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422).